# How to get the id of a button that fired a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button

```
   <button onclick="DeletaItem('template','1234')" id="btn">Deletar_func</button>
```

And the function

```
   function DeletaItem(tipo,id_cripto){
       alert(tipo+id_cripto);
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
   }
```

Why the second alert is undefined?

Comment: `$(event.target).attr("id")` should do the trick for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second alert is undefined because **this** does not refer to the button, it actually refers to the **window** object.

You need to either send **this** to the function, change the onclick to the following:

```
onclick="DeletaItem(this, 'template', '1234')"
```

and also change the function as follows:

```
function DeletaItem(button, tipo, id_cripto) {
    alert(tipo + id_cripto);
    alert(button.id);
}
```

or leave the onclick as it is and use **event.target** within the function instead of **this**.

```
function DeletaItem(tipo, id_cripto) {
    alert(tipo + id_cripto);
    alert(event.target.id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

OR

```
 <button onclick="DeletaItem(this,'template','1234')" id="btn">Deletar_func</button>


function DeletaItem(obj,tipo,id_cripto){

   alert(tipo+id_cripto);
   alert($(obj).attr('id'));
   alert(obj.id);
   // alert(this); if uncomment this, you will see it is eqaul window object

}
```

when function called with onclick attribute, it's don't became an object like  first one, so you can't use `this`; here `this` is window objectm but in first one, jQuery object will be passed